# How do you publish interactive adobe animate .swf, or mac/pc projector onto a website?

Tags: adobe-animate, publishing, interaction, actionscript

I have a whole library of interactive (chemistry) learning animations with voice annotation that I had hoped to publish in a dedicated website before the flash player got End of Life and changed everything. No problem, I thought, I'll just export these as projectors (mac and pc) and that would work around the issue. But when I tried it, while the projectors will run (sometimes) if I open it with my mac (the .swf certainly plays well), external users see the projectors as folders, .exe files don't open, and macs can't even see the app. Sometimes uploading the files become zipped. Frustrating. What am I missing?

Comment: Windows projectors are saved as .exe, Mac as .app - neither will work on the other platform. .swf, on the other hand is cross-platform & can be played on VLC [also cross-platform]. Your question really isn't quite clear on exactly what you've done, or what the results are.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Using Adobe Animate, I prepared an animation with interactive elements (buttons, input text box, click-drag/unclick stopdrag, etc. with voice over narration). Under publish settings ... I checked .swf, mac projector and win projector, and then publish. In the folder, I see icons for the .swf, and the two projectors (I'm on a Mac, so the win projector looks like a blank file folder). The .swf and projector work well on the computer where they were generated but the moment I transfer it to a website, put them on a USB memory stick, attach to an email, the projectors turn into folders.

Comment: Mac apps **are** folders, just the Mac doesn't see them that way, intentionally. Put them on a PC & because Windows has no clue what to do with them, they're just folders again. Drop them back to a Mac & they should automagically become apps once more. An swf & an exe ought to look like flat files on both platforms.

Comment: It is true that uploading a Mac Projector into Google Drive transforms it into a folder. Downloading the folder into the same Mac, zips it. Unzipping it, transforms it back to a Mac projector, BUT clicking on this projector gives the following message "<file name in quotes> is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash." - with a "cancel" and "move to trash" as the only options.

Comment: Same thing happens if Ii upload the Mac projector into a Course Tools website (like those made by Blackboard). The upshot is that I can't deliver the projectors to users.

Comment: I'd guess non-Macs don't know what to do with them & manage to break them. Zip them first.

Comment: Zipping the projector, dropping the zipped file into Google Drive, downloading the zipped file into the same Mac that generated the projector, unzipping it, then clicking on the projector icon - does not work. I get the same "damaged" message.

Comment: Ahh… it's probably a certificate issue on newer macOS. 'unidentified developer'.

Comment: How do I find out if it is that? How do fix it if it is that?

Comment: Right click then select Open, rather than double-click. if that launches it successfully then that's possibly the reason; it should bypass quarantine that way. Certifying is way above my pay-grade, you'd have to check out Apple's developer documentation.

Comment: From Adobe Customer Care:



"...we have checked it and its a bug that our team is working on the fix. 



hopefully, it will be fixed in future updates."



:/   So now I have to decide if I will invest upwards of a year or two creating the learning modules that may never see the light of day - or, if the bug fix comes with another overhaul of the scripting language, having to spend additional time porting the modules to the new language.



>sigh<



Anyway, thanks for your attention to this, Tetsujin (and everyone else who read but did not post).